# XSLT translate backslash to double backslash

Tags: json, xslt, path, unc, slash

I need to transform this value:

```
    <MediaFile>F:\DEMO\TEST\HELLO.pm4</MediaFile>
```

to this:

```
<MediaFile>F:\\DEMO\\TEST\\HELLO.pm4</MediaFile>
```

I have tried a lot of thing, translate, concat, substring and replace but I didn't succeeded.

Here's precisely, what I've tried:

Source file:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Asset version="1.0">
    <Target>
    <Name>HELLO</Name>
    <MediaFile>F:\DEMO\TEST\HELLO.mp4</MediaFile>

</Target>
</Asset>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:variable name="MediaFile">
            <xsl:value-of select="Asset/Target/MediaFile"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="Media">
            <xsl:value-of select="replace($MediaFile,'\','\\')"/>
        </xsl:variable> 

            <xsl:element name="Media">
                <xsl:value-of select="$Media"/>
            </xsl:element>  
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm using xslt 2.0

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Which version of XSLT can you use? XSLT 2 or 3 offer all XPath 2 or 3 functions like `replace` https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace

Comment: XSLT 2.0, I tried replace but didn't get anything good out of it, i'm sure i'm not doing it right..

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what you have tried (in XSLT 2.0, with replace). You might not have been far off....

Comment: I just edit my question, yes I might have been closed to it at some point...

Comment: The thing is that I can replace anything else with no issue but the back slash seems to be the problem here... any solutions ?

Comment: Backslash is often used to change the behavior of the next character. Ex: \n represents a new line character. As such, to indicate a literal backslash it's often necessary to write '\\'.  So, try replacing '\\' with '\\\\'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to replace the below

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace($MediaFile,'\','\\')"/>
```

with

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace($MediaFile,'\\','\\\\')" />
```

In many programming languages, **backslash** is used to as an escape character to indicate the character following it needs special treatment. In this case, you would need to escape the character being replaced `\` with `\\` and also need to replace `\\` with `\\\\` (two backslashes).

Following question would help provide some detail explanation [What does back slash "\" really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254887/what-does-back-slash-really-mean)

Additionally, in the template that you have shared, the desired output is `text`, so there is no need to create an element named `Media` as it would come into picture if the desired output is XML. So the template code can be optimized as

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(Asset/Target/MediaFile,'\\','\\\\')" />
</xsl:template>
```

Output

```
F:\\DEMO\\TEST\\HELLO.mp4
```